# Loading delimited file with unequal number of rows at each column

Tags: python, numpy, load

I am trying to load this kind of file but I get the "wrong number of columns" error when I'm doing the following:

```
import numpy
ux = numpy.loadtxt('ux.txt',delimiter=None)
```

The file is like that:

```
   .2496455E-03  -.1076763E-03   .2617193E-03  -.1371510E-03   .2694375E-03
  -.1649617E-03   .2751468E-03  -.1895755E-03   .2890017E-03  -.2926575E-03
   .1313772E-03
```

I could have the remainder be loaded as zeros, I don't care that much about it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: look at `np.genfromtxt`

Comment: `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` accept input from any iterable that gives them lines.  I'd load the file, pad each line as needed, and pass them on.

Comment: `genfromtxt` lets you specify column widths rather than delimiters.  That might work better here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was the following and it worked successfully.

As I wanted to make a column with all the numbers at the end I did this:

```
uxf = []

for line in ux:
    uxs = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
    uxf = numpy.hstack((uxf,uxs))
```

That way I stacked all lines, which is what I eventually wanted. The [float(x) for x in line.split()] doesn't care about the number of columns within the line.

Comment: So you just want all the numbers, without assuming that the short lines have missing values.

Comment: I want all the numbers. Just because of the nature of the files, I just can't know how many columns the last row will have.

This parser did the job.